# Android GUI frozen when SwipeRefreshLayout is not used

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, swiperefreshlayout

I want the swipe-to-refresh functionality in my app, but I have a problem: Just by adding the XML for it it breaks the GUI. In the moment when the app is being swiped, I can still use the GUI, but the moment it stops or I come back to the particular page it breaks again. Here is the activity XML where I add the SwipeRefreshLayout tag which breaks the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.something.myapp.UserListActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/user_list" />
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/user_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: By the way, I can use ScrollView or ListView instead of RecyclerView and if I add the refresh functionality in the Java code, the actual content refresh will always work. It only messes up the GUI, this XML...

Answer (score 0):

Well it only took me a whole day, but I figured it out... I didn't understand the XML logic so well, but after a while I realized what to do. My solution was to not put SwipeRefreshLayout within CoordinatorLayout, but the other way around - put CoordinatorLayout in SwipeRefreshLayout, putting SwipeRefreshLayout at the top of that xml file's hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that SwipeRefreshLayout must be the parent of the view and should have only ONE child, as you can see in the Android developers documentation:

*This layout should be made the parent of the view that will be refreshed as a result of the gesture and can only support one direct child.*

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

When you changed Layouts, this rule was not broken anymore.

Comment: Yep, the documentation was kinda clear, I just had to read it up and experiment, not be afraid of xml.